# KeyPressed Called Multiple times on Update

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add an attack to my character, everything works fine except my button its called multiple times by click (I'm not holding the key down, and its called in average 4 times).

Thats my Update method:

```
void Update() {
    attackArea.enabled = false;
    InputCharacter();
    MoveAttackArea();
    SetAnimation();
    ApplyColorFilters();
}
```

and my InputCharacter method:

```
void InputCharacter() {
    direction = Vector2.zero;
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.B)) {
        lastAttackTime = currentTime;
        Attack();
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        Move(Vector2.up);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
        Move(Vector2.down);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
        Move(Vector2.left);
    } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
        Move(Vector2.right);
    }
}
```

also my Attack method:

```
private void Attack() {
    Debug.Log("attacking");
    animator.SetTrigger("attack");
    attackArea.enabled = true;
}
```

I don't know if the this part its related but:

The log show multiple times and my animations are playing twice (when I play an object destruction animation it runs twice, I don't know if its related)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
Input.GetKey
```

with

```
Input.GetKeyDown
```